# How to automatically report system problems detected

Tags: system, bug-reporting

Occasionally I get swarms of "System problem (problem) detected" errors, or even just one by itself.

I don't want to turn them off altogether, because I think it's good to report them but I also don't want to click through each of them every time and click "Report Problem"

Can I configure it so they are automatically reported without prompting me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#A4._Collect_information_about_the_bug says that information about bugs and crashes is reported automatically in stable Ubuntu versions (last one would be `14.04`) without apport appearing.

Since you see apport, most probably you are using Ubuntu `14.10` - version under active development. "click through each of them every time" implies that you are asked to report 5-6 errors on every boot - or at least I had that problem. Those are created by "persistent bug reports" that for one or another reason are not deleted after submitting them. After clicking through reports, you may manually clean `/var/crash/` folder - it will only contain information you've already submitted. All new crashes should be inspected nevertheless.

All in all, I wouldn't recommend auto-submitting, since then you yourself wouldn't  know something was off until system exploded.

Comment: "that information about bugs and crashes is reported automatically in stable Ubuntu versions" AFAICT it doesn't say anything like that. It does say a different distinction: in development builds reports go to launchpad, but in stable they go to errors.ubuntu.com